# Rails: Find an object based on two of its has_one through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-one, has-one-through

My rails app has `User`, `Convo` and `UserConvo` models. UserConvo belong_to both a User and a Convo. Convo looks like this:

```
class Convo < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :host_user_convo,  ->{ where role: 'host' }, class_name: 'UserConvo'
  has_one :host, through: :host_user_convo, source: :user
  has_one :guest_user_convo, ->{ where role: 'guest' }, class_name: 'UserConvo'
  has_one :guest, through: :guest_user_convo, source: :user

  ...

end
```

What I want to do, if query for a Convo which has a particular host and guest.

I've tried this:

```
Convo.joins(:host, :guest).where('host.id = foo AND guest.id = bar').references(:host, :guest)
```

And some permutations with `includes` instead of `joins`.

Essentially, how can I find an object based on two of it's has_one through associations. Keeping in mind that both `convo.host` and `convo.guest` as Users.

Comment: Where is the column `role` defined?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you do the join, the `host` join is called `user_convos` and the `guest` join is called `guest_user_convos_convos_join`

So, if you have a host with an id of 3 and guest with an id of 4 the following seems to work:

```
Convo.joins(:host, :guest).where("user_convos.user_id = 3 AND guest_user_convos_convos_join.user_id = 4")
```